# How to bind by reference using function that returns object?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular

I have some object in my Component:

```
this.user = Authentication.user;
```

Which works just fine - it copies the reference, and if `Authentication.user` changes, `this.user` in my Component changes as well.

However, I am wondering, if it is possible to do the following:

```
this.user = Authentication.getUser()
```

where Authentication.getUser :

```
getUser(){
    return this.user;
}
```

However, this does not seem to copy reference to user from Authentication.

Am I doing something wrong here, or it not possible?

**UPDATE**

Actually, it works pretty nice:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ULuSl6CIBCzi7gcsLu3R?p=preview

Comment: Hard to tell. It's not obvious what `Authentication.user` is, and where it comes from. " if Authentication.user changes, this.user in my Component changes as well." probably means when a property of `Authentication.user` changes, otherwise this would not be the case. Please try to create a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, sure thing, i will do it in few mins!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, it actually works, but doesnt work with primitives. Do you know if Angular2 fixed issue with binding to a primitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to fix this for primitives.

TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript and you can't change how JavaScript handles primitive types.

If you want to synchronize, create an Observable that sends value changes, then the receiver can subscribe and gets notified about changes and update his copy of the value.